# Asp.Net LINQ to combine three tables

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net, linq

I want to show in my view three columns:

```
======================================
UserName      | Email    | Role Name
======================================    
codelover12     code@g.g    Student    
kimmy45634      kimy@c.c    Teacher    
======================================
```

so initially what I was thinking is that

I can join `Id` in `AspNetUsers` table with `UserId` in `AspNetUserRoles` table, and also join `Id` in `AspNetRoles` so I can figure out who has which role.

I was trying like this:

```
var model = from users in db.Users
            join userRoles in db.AspNetUserRoles on users.Id equals roles.UserId
            join role in db.Roles on role.Id equals userRoles.RoleId 
            select new { users.UserName, users.Email, role.Name };
```

but figured out that I cannot access AspNetUserRoles. 
I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "cannot access AspNetUserRoles"?  Does your query give you an error?  At the very least it should be `user.Id equals userRoles.UserId` though you should consider using Navigation properties instead.

Comment: it gives me an error on db.AspNetUserRoles saying that ApplicationDbContext does not contain a definition for 'AspNetUserRoles'

Comment: My guess is that is a many to many table, and EF doesn't create entities for those.  Instead you should use the Navigation properties. Something like `from user in db.Users from role in user.Roles`

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured it out.

Easiest way to do it was adding this line of code to IdentityModels.cs

```
public DbSet<IdentityUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
```

then you can now have access to AspNetUserRoles, and write codes like

```
var findRole = (from userRole in db.UserRoles
                join role in db.Roles on
                userRole.RoleId equals role.Id
                where userRole.UserId == Id
                select role.Name).ToList();
```

Hope this can help others who have similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

EF create cross table AspNetUserRoles automatically. So, you can use navigation properties or do smth like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{    
    modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUser>()
        .HasMany(x => x.Roles)
        .WithMany(x => x.AspNetUsers)
    .Map(x =>
    {
        x.ToTable("AspNetUserRoles"); // third table is named Cookbooks
        x.MapLeftKey("AspNetUserId");
        x.MapRightKey("RoleId");
    });
}
```